# I got too many server authentication error

Tags: linux

This is when I do tail -1000 messages

```
Aug 10 03:02:51 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:02:51 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:02:53 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:02:53 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtopless]
Aug 10 03:02:53 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:53 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:02:53 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:54 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:02:54 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:02:54 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [chickswimsuitcom]
Aug 10 03:02:55 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [sunadultcom]
Aug 10 03:02:55 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:02:55 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:55 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:55 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:02:56 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [d7c]
Aug 10 03:02:56 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:02:56 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [tripstockscom]
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefxcom]
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [.timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:02:57 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:58 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:02:58 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:02:58 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:02:58 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:02:59 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:02:59 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:01 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:02 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [.sunadult.com]
Aug 10 03:03:02 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:02 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:03:02 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [datingblondeadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator@timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefx.com]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [chickswimsuit]
Aug 10 03:03:03 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:04 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:05 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [tripstocks]
Aug 10 03:03:05 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:05 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [mypicturessiteadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtoplesscom]
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:06 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [computergamesonadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:07 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:07 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:07 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrators@timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefx]
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [esults]
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator@sunadult.com]
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:08 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:09 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:09 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:09 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:03:10 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [smartvehiclefinancecom]
Aug 10 03:03:10 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [titiesporniestnet]
Aug 10 03:03:10 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:11 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [brunettedvdadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [tripstockscom]
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefxcom]
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:12 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [timemarriage]
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:13 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [stockmarketof]
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [chickswimsuitcom]
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:14 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:15 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:15 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtopless]
Aug 10 03:03:15 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:15 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrators@sunadult.com]
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:16 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [tripstocks]
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [timemarriagecom]
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:17 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefx.com]
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:18 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:19 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:19 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [stockmarketofcom]
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [sunadult]
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:20 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtoplesscom]
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [chickswimsuit]
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin@timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:21 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:22 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:22 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:22 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [smartvehiclefinanceadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:22 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:23 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:23 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:23 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefx]
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [titiesporniestadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [mypicturessite]
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:24 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [italian-pussy]
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtopless]
Aug 10 03:03:25 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [esults]
Aug 10 03:03:26 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:03:27 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:27 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:28 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [timemarriage@timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:03:28 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:28 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nude-miss]
Aug 10 03:03:28 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [computergamesoncom]
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefxcom]
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:29 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [stockmarketofadmin]
Aug 10 03:03:30 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:30 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [m]
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [datingblondecom]
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:31 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [INFO] New connection from 220.161.126.80
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtoplesscom]
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] New connection from 27.153.248.48
Aug 10 03:03:32 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
Aug 10 03:03:33 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:33 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [chickswimsuitcom]
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@110.85.68.75) [INFO] New connection from 110.85.68.75
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [marriagefx.com]
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@118.186.140.18) [INFO] New connection from 118.186.140.18
Aug 10 03:03:34 host pure-ftpd: (?@222.186.58.97) [INFO] New connection from 222.186.58.97
Aug 10 03:03:35 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [timemarriage.com]
Aug 10 03:03:35 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:35 host pure-ftpd: (?@199.193.71.80) [INFO] New connection from 199.193.71.80
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [sunadultcom]
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [brunettedvdcom]
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@112.86.10.158) [INFO] New connection from 112.86.10.158
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [admin]
Aug 10 03:03:36 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:37 host pure-ftpd: (?@220.161.126.80) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [administrator]
Aug 10 03:03:38 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [nekkidtopless]
Aug 10 03:03:38 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] Logout.
Aug 10 03:03:38 host pure-ftpd: (?@27.153.248.48) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [root]
Aug 10 03:03:39 host pure-ftpd: (?@111.175.124.84) [INFO] New connection from 111.175.124.84
```

What is it? how do I block these?

I used cpanel cphulk. However, cphulk only listed the IP as list of brute force attack. 27.153.248.48 is listed as one of the IP in cphulk.

However, my server seems to keep receiving connection from such IP just fine.

Answer (score 5):

This is just normal "background noise" you see with about every internet facing server. If you don't need an ftp server (you shouldn't, prefer SFTP instead), turn it off. Other than that, make sure you have good passwords and maybe install something like Fail2Ban to block hosts repeatedly trying to connect unsucessfully.

Comment: What are your thoughts on using only SFTP, but keeping ftp running with a "one strike you're out" via fail2ban and banning for 6-12 months or so? Seems like an easy way to partially immunize a server from possible botnets.